# Android RecyclerView with AdView- best practices AdMob

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, adview

I'm finishing my first mobile application and I want to add some AdViews at the bottom of the views. I read the AdMob policies but I'm still not sure is that the right way of ad presentation. I have a recycler view and ad on the bottom. User is scrolling down but the ad is still visible, at the end of the view I add extra 50dp padding to fit the ad with the last item so it's not overlaying it. RecyclerView items are not clickable so it won't be a miss click for ad. Is that a good way or I have to change it? Screenshot for a better explanation.

[recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXxHN.jpg)

[last item in recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCDth.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ensure that your ad does not overlap with content using LinearLayouts and layout_weight something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/detail_activity_bar"></include>

    <SomeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/home_grid"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewGallery"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/home_banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

adSize BANNER suits well for most of the devices, while SMART_BANNER does overlap with bigger screen mobiles as per my experience.

with above implementation you will never get admob banner policy violations

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at [`MergedAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter) (still in alpha). It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply, my adapter looks like this

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BenefitsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_benefits"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#109689"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:background="@color/grey_background"
            android:id="@+id/benefits_recycler"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2503474669022915/4441412233">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```